# Memory Size allocation and deallocation

Tags: c

Whenever We assign data types, we say it that it takes memory space. Where does it take memory space? Does it take on our program file size? When we write a program and save it. Will the size becomes greater on float than int by 2 bytes remaining other content same?

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"Will the size becomes greater on float than int by 2 bytes"` -- On most modern platforms, a `float` has the same size as an `int` (4 bytes). Therefore, there probably willl be no difference between these two data types.

Comment: Stack or Heap, or in the executable itself for constants.

Comment: Data that is initialized to a certain value takes space in the program file, because the initial value must be stored somewhere. However, uninitialized data probably does not increase the program file size, because it does not have to be stored in the program file itself. It must only be stored in memory.

Comment: Types don't take space, variables do.  In general this is highly optimized and only global variables with a non-zero initialization value make the program grow.  Runtime memory usage does grow with more variables.  Modern machines have to much of it available that this is very hard to notice.

Comment: Yes, data type declaration doesn't take space. But, let me clarify the doubt.

Comment: Here, 
int a=67;

Comment: @OmkarBhattarai: That will probably take 4 bytes of space in the program file, to store the value `67`.

Comment: and 
double a=78;

in two different programs..


I saved those two files.

Will those files have same size??




Question arises here!

If not, what does it  mean that, double takes more size than int.(Of course we need to use variables)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, yes.
When we use double a=67 instead of int a=87, file size increases by 4 bytes??

Am I right?

Comment: @OmkarBhattarai: In principle yes. However, if you activate compiler optimizations, the compiler may be able to optimize away a variable initialization, if that value is never used. Also, for technical reasons, the individual sections of an executable file may have to be a multiple of a certain size. This depends on the platform (compiler and operating system) that you are using. For that reason, it is possible that the total file size may not change at all, or it may change by a much larger value.

Comment: For example, on Microsoft Windows, it is common for the individual sections of an executable file to have an "alignment" of 512 bytes. This means that the size of all sections must be a multiple of 512 bytes. Therefore, if one section need 4 bytes more data, then it its likely that this won't change the total file size, unless this causes the section to go past the next 512 byte boundary. In that case, the total file size will be 512 bytes larger, even if you only add 4 bytes of data.

Comment: As you can see, the situation is a bit more complex than you are stating. But you are correct, in principle. Every platform behaves a bit differently. But you don't have to worry about all of these details.

Comment: That's enough for me to clear my doubt. Thanks Mr. @AndreasWenzel